# How to store fingerprint in database

Tags: flutter, fingerprint, sqflite

I want to store fingerprint in sqflite flutter database. But I am having difficulty implementing it. Here I have created a sqflite database to store phoneNumber, otp that has been used and also fingerprints that have been saved.

```
Future<Database> initDb() async {
    final databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(databasesPath, 'data.db');
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (
        Database db,
        int version,
        ) async {
      await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        phoneNumber TEXT
        isOTP BOOLEAN
        isFingerprint BOOLEAN
      )
    ''');
    });
  }
```

I hope to be able to take fingerprints from each expected phoneNumber.

```
class CekSecurityLoginBloc
    extends Bloc<CekSecurityLoginEvent, CekSecurityLoginState> {
  CekSecurityLoginBloc() : super(CekSecurityLoginInitial()) {
    on<CekSecurityLogin>((event, emit) async {
      bool isSecurityFingerprint =
          await AppSharedPreferences.isSecurityFingerprint();

      try {
         if (isSecurityFingerprint) {
          emit(SecurityFingerprint());
        } else {
          emit(SecurityPin());
        }
      } catch (error) {
        emit(SecurityPin());
      }
    });
    on<ClearStatusLogin>((event, emit) async => emit(CekSecurityInitial()));
  }
}
```

Previously I used sharedpreferences to store fingerprints. However, I realized that if I logged in with a different phoneNumber, the shared preferences fingerprint would be static and not dynamic according to the phoneNumber.